# Undefined Method Error for strftime in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, debugging

I just started learning Rails, I'm having trouble trying to format a time.  I have a Ticket model which has many contact logs, and I want to format the created_at timestamp in a view.  When I use this code:

```
<% @contacts.each do |contact| %>
  <p><%= contact.created_at.strftime("%B %e, %Y") %></p>
  <p><%= contact.author %></p>
  <p><%= contact.description %><p>
<% end %>
```

to print out the contacts associated with a ticket, the page displays the error:

```
undefined method `strftime' for nil:NilClass
```

However, when I use

```
<% @contacts.each do |contact| %>
  <p><%= contact.created_at %></p>
  <p><%= contact.author %></p>
  <p><%= contact.description %><p>
<% end %>
```

a date is printed (something like 2012-08-26 05:16:15 UTC), along with the expected values for author and description.

I've looked at all of the timestamp values for the contact objects in my database, and none have created_at values of anything other than times.  Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Are any of the `created_at` values in your table `NULL`?

Comment: Are all the `@contacts` saved to the database? If there is one that you newly initialized and not saved, then its `created_at` will indeed be nil. For example, if you initialize a new @contact in the controller, and on the next line do `@contacts = Contact.all`, the last `Contact` will not have a `created_at` because it isn't saved yet.

Comment: Thanks guys, the problem was that I was displaying a form for a new contact right above the code in my question, which created but did not save a new contact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps one of your records has created_at set to nil, Try this:

```
<p><%= contact.created_at.present? ? contact.created_at.strftime("%B %e, %Y") : contact.created_at%></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

`created_at` could return not only string. 
Did you tried this:
`<%= contact.created_at.to_s.strftime("%B %e, %Y") %>`?